# JQuery client side search

Tags: jquery, search, client-side, javascript

I have a database table filled with ~300 records. This table includes columns for Name, Address, zip code, State, etc.

I would to perform a client-side search on this table using JQuery. Do you have any library recommendations or best practices that I should consider? What are the disadvantages I should consider?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good success with [Datatables](http://datatables.net/).

One of the main reasons I chose it over others is that my sites use jqueryui and themeroller and it has built in support for themeroller. It also includes very nice support for server side paging if you need it in the future and all the usual things you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

By table I assume you mean database.

There is **NO** client side javascript that can look into a server side database.

In order to *look* into the database you would need some ajax calls with javascript to the server side to get the information from the database

Comment: I'm going to pull the entire table with a ruby .all method. Give it to the client. I want a library to search that data.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend jQuery Grid since they already have done the hard work for you: http://www.trirand.com/blog/
Now this is taking care of many types of complex search params and an ajax call is fired everytime even though you can leverage the caching provided by jquery ajax methods. If you want to allow flexibility and let your users try out different kinds of search this is your tool. You can also code a custom utility if you want to just target a few scenarios.